# How to upgrade OSX on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, software-update

I need to upgrade my MacBook Pro 15 inch (2012) OS X from 10.11.6 to 10.13.6 or later.
However, I have downloaded several updates for 10.13 all the way down to 10.12.6 and in every case it says I need to have a prior operation system such as 10.12 for 10.12.6 to be installed.

In other words I can't seem to find an OS X system that I can install because I don't have the latest system for the update. So are all these OS systems updates only that require a previous version? Apple's download website just shows updates.

Where can I find a complete new OS to download so I can apply updates?

Answer (score 1):

Major releases aren‘t distributed as updates, they need to be downloaded from the Mac App Store:

- Open the App Store application on your Mac
- Search for „Mojave“
- Install

Comment: If I click on Updates in my Settings panel, it shows there are no updates.

Comment: @Dave as the answer says major updates are from the App Store updates via Software update are just minpr versions

Comment: I have tried at least 4 software updates and they all say I need to have a certain OS version already installed.

Comment: @Dave You need to install the latest OS from the App Store, see edited answer

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I did search for Mojave in the App store and found it and installed it.  It was not intuitive to me to have to search for an OS when the App Store kept telling me I did not need any updates.

Comment: @Dave Apple uses "up**date**" to refer to minor version changes, like 10.11.5 -> 10.11.6, and "up**grade**" to refer to major version changes, like 10.11.x -> 10.12.x. You didn't need any updates, you needed an upgrade.